# How do we discourage replying to trolls?

Tags: discussion

I saw a troll post and flagged it; didn't vote, didn't comment, didn't do anything but flag.

I saw people replying/voting/commenting breaking the adage "don't feed the trolls". How people don't know to not reply to trolls is beyond me. The question got dealt with by a mod quickly thankfully.

How do we discourage people from replying to trolls?

Comment: I don't have the stats, but if troll posts are rare and got deal with quickly, I don't think more efforts should be put on it.

Comment: As someone who spent 20 years of his life online, I know full well not to feed trolls. But sometimes you're bored, and they are just so darn "cute" (in a twisted and silly way), that trolling them back just seems mandatory.

Comment: "How people don't know to not reply to trolls is beyond me." How people don't know the quadratic formula is beyond me. But it's there, we deal with it as best we can.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "As someone who spent 20 years of his life online..." That's gonna me in 20 years from now.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Funny, because apparently you've been on here for 2 years already. ;)

Comment: The other side is when everything becomes trolling though. You can simply flag what you dont like as trolling and else. Your status on the site gives credibility to your classifications though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila There is nothing like "trolling back", there is only trolling

Comment: "How people don't know to not reply to trolls is beyond me." The problem might be identifying trolls. Sometimes you need to exchange a few messages with someone before you're sure they're not after honest help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After flagging a comment that you believe to be trolling, flag any replies to it as obsolete. This makes it easier for the mods to nuke the whole, irrelevant conversation. Of course, this happens automatically when removing questions and answers, so additional flags aren't necessary in those cases.

As for people replying in the first place, I don't think there's anything anyone can do about that.